# How to keep comments in ruamel

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I need to sort a YAML file with comments. I'm using ruamel.yaml library to keep comments from YAML, but when I do sort items comments are placed in wrong place.

```py
people = """\
# manager of project
- title: manager

# owner of company
- title: owner
"""

import ruamel.yaml, sys

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
arr = yaml.load(people)
arr  = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x['title'])
yaml.dump(arr, sys.stdout)
```

With this code I'm getting following output:

```yaml
- title: manager

# owner of company
- title: owner
```

During sort comment for the first element is gone. How I can keep first comment for the list?

Answer (score 1):

Your first comment, at the beginning of the document, has no
preceeding node and gets a special place on the `arr` object (which is
of type `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq`). You can inspect this by
doing `print(arr.ca)` (ca for comment attribute), directly after
loading.

After loading there is a second comment attribute attached to the dict
like object constructed from the mapping `arr[0]` and a third comment
attribute attached to a dict like object constructed from `arr[1]` (in
much the same way as the first comment is attached to `arr`).

The sorting operation is **not** done in place, hence only the
comments associated with the elements that are sorted stay put. The
`arr` after the asignment (a simple `list`), of the result of
`sorted()` is not even the same type as the `arr` loaded from YAML (a
`CommentedSeq`), and of course has no comments associated with it.

So what you need to do is preserve the comment information, make the
result of sorted of the appropriate type and then assign the preserved
information to that object. Fortunately this only requires one changed
and one added line to your code:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

people = """\
# manager of project
- title: manager

# owner of company
- title: owner
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
arr = yaml.load(people)
root_comment = arr.ca
arr  = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x['title']))
arr._yaml_comment = root_comment
yaml.dump(arr, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# manager of project
- title: manager

# owner of company
- title: owner
```

However in general this kind of extensive manipulation will get you
into trouble. It is probably better to try doing this with an in-place sort.

Comment: I gave bad example, with this input it also gives wrong output:

```# owner of company
  - title: owner

# manager of project
- title: manager
```